# setting _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING to 0

Tags: c++

How can i set _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING  to 0

I tried setting using #define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0 at the start of the main.cpp
I tried in setting preprocessor definition

:( but with no success

Thanks in advance

Uday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry It was my mistake

I had to write this in preprocessor defnition 
__HAS __ITERATOR __DEBUGGING=0; __SECURE_SCL=0;

not

__HAS __ITERATOR __DEBUGGING 0; __SECURE _SCL 0;

Answer (score 2):

You need to define it before you include any headers.
Also note that if you are using precompiled headers,

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
#include <stdafx.h>
```

(where stdafx.h is a precompiled header)

will *not* work.  The precompiled header must be the first thing in the file.